# Django 2 different error: "local variable referenced before assignment" + "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. "

Tags: python, django

I try to render this view for a Django project and i can get out from these two errors.
The first one is "local variable 'list_of_data' referenced before the assignment. After I change the scope of that variable I get another error "The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."
I tried a few solutions founded around on the web but i couldn't resolve them.

Here is the views code:

```
def forecast(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = urllib.parse.quote_plus(request.POST['city'])

        source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+ city +'&units=metric&appid=API_KEY').read()

        list_of_data = json.loads(source)

    day = datetime.datetime.today()
    today_date = int(day.strftime('%d'))


    forcast_data_list = {} # dictionary to store json data

    #looping to get value and put it in the dictionary
    for c in range(0, list_of_data['cnt']):
        date_var1 = list_of_data['list'][c]['dt_txt']
        date_time_obj1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_var1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        
        
        if int(date_time_obj1.strftime('%d')) == today_date or int(date_time_obj1.strftime('%d')) == today_date+1:
            # print(date_time_obj1.strftime('%d %a'))
            if int(date_time_obj1.strftime('%d')) == today_date+1:
                today_date += 1
            forcast_data_list[today_date] = {}
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['day'] = date_time_obj1.strftime('%A')
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['date'] = date_time_obj1.strftime('%d %b, %Y')
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['time'] = date_time_obj1.strftime('%I:%M %p')
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['FeelsLike'] = list_of_data['list'][c]['main']['feels_like']

            forcast_data_list[today_date]['temperature'] = list_of_data['list'][c]['main']['temp']
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['temperature_max'] = list_of_data['list'][c]['main']['temp_max']
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['temperature_min'] = list_of_data['list'][c]['main']['temp_min']

            forcast_data_list[today_date]['description'] = list_of_data['list'][c]['weather'][0]['description']
            forcast_data_list[today_date]['icon'] = list_of_data['list'][c]['weather'][0]['icon']

            today_date += 1
        else:
            pass
    #returning the context with all the data to the forecast.html
    context = {
        'forcast_data_list':forcast_data_list
    }

    return render(request, 'forecast.html', context)
```

If i run this view i get the "local data referenced before assignment" error.
PS: For some reason the first time it works...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems that the indentation of the code you've included is incorrect. Make sure the indentation levels match your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request.method is not a POST, list_of_data never gets defined because of the if statement. Define list_of_date = [] outside of the if statement.